# Confluent + kafka docker using confluent image + total kafka docker parameters

Tags: docker-compose, confluent-platform

we are using kafka docker from confluent , and we installed the latest kafka docker image

now we need to set the parameter/s in `docker-compose.yml` file

but from confluent documentation we not see what are the total kafka parameters and parameters values that we can used for kafka docker

any idea how to find the parameters per kafka docker image version ?

https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/cos-docker-quickstart.html

Comment: I am really not understand why all the expert here cant answer on my question

Comment: I think you can use any of the broker properties defined in Kafka documentation but from memory there may be some quirk when you put them in your docker-compose.yml .I have this set up on my laptop and can have a quick look tomorrow UK time.

Comment: but I need all the parameters and in doc I have only partial

Comment: It took me a while to find it from the quickstart page too - I think they should provide a link off to the full configuration info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-kafka-configuration

Basically you use all the standard broker configurations, but prefix with `KAFKA_` , use capitals instead of lowercase, and use underscores instead of `.`

The full set of broker configuration parameters for Confluent Kafka is at https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html